# Retrieving same file name(e.g - a.xyz) from different directories which only difference is the suffix (e.g - surf_001, surf_002, surf_003)

Tags: file, directory, operating-system, glob

I have a directory with subdirectories like this.

```
my_directory/  
├── surf_001/  
|     ├── a.xyz  
├── surf_002/.  
|     └── a.xyz  
├── surf_003/  
|     ├── a.xyz
```

I could retrieve a.xyz of surf_001 and so far my code looks like this

```
import numpy as np  
import glob  
import os

num ='1'  
print(num.zfill(3))

file=os.path.join('/home', 'sg', 'scratch', 'slabs', 'cool_100', 'surf_001', 'a.xyz')  
print(file)

filenames = glob.glob(file)   
print(filenames)

oh_den=[]  
count=0  
for lines in filenames:       
    outfile = open(lines,'r')   
    data = outfile.readlines()  
    outfile.close()   
    for f in data:   
        if 'H' in f:      
            count = count + 1  
    print(count)
```

this gives me what I want for first folder, can someone tell me how to edit this to get other files. I have folders upto surf_100

Answer (score 0):

This is a situation that is a little difficult for the built-in glob, not impossible though. With that said, there is a Python library called [`wcmatch`](https://facelessuser.github.io/wcmatch/glob/) that makes this a little easier (full disclosure, I'm the author of said library).

This library allows you to implement [extended globbing](https://www.linuxjournal.com/content/bash-extended-globbing) via the `EXTGLOB` flag. To demonstrate, we will use the `globmatch` function to match some files:

```py
>>> from wcmatch import glob
>>> glob.globmatch('my_directory/surf_100/a.xyz', '**/surf_+([0-9])/a.xyz', flags=glob.GLOBSTAR | glob.EXTGLOB)
True
>>> glob.globmatch('my_directory/surf_003/a.xyz', '**/surf_+([0-9])/a.xyz', flags=glob.GLOBSTAR | glob.EXTGLOB)
True
```

As you can see, we are using the `+(...)` pattern which is similar to doing something like `(...)+` in regex. Essentially we are saying we want one or more of whatever is contained within the pattern list. And in our pattern list, it is numbers.

In your case, you would probably want something like this:

```py
from wcmatch import glob
file = '/home/sg/scratch/slabs/cool_100/surf_+([0-9])/a.xyz'
filenames = glob.glob(file, flags=glob.EXTGLOB)
```

There are other ways to do this as well, such as using brace expansion. This is a little less efficient as it does pattern expansion turning one pattern into many but gives you the flexibility to specify a range.

```py
>>> glob.globmatch('my_directory/surf_003/a.xyz', '**/surf_{001..100}/a.xyz', flags=glob.GLOBSTAR | glob.BRACE)
True
>>> glob.globmatch('my_directory/surf_101/a.xyz', '**/surf_{001..100}/a.xyz', flags=glob.GLOBSTAR | glob.BRACE)
False
```

If using an external library is not an option, I am sure there will be plenty of answers showcasing how to do so with regular glob, but I imagine they might not be quite as straightforward.